# Logging Application Block-Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1

Tags: enterprise

In Logging Application Block in Logger.Write it takes event id as one of the parameter which is integer.So how to decide what should be passed as event id?

Answer (score 0):

btw, do you really need to use the eventId? I think you can just pass the string you want to log:-

```
Logger.Write("SomeMessage");
```

EDIT :- I meant there should be another overload which takes just the string you want to write.

EDIT :- From [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/GetLoggingWithEntLib.aspx) :-

> EventId - a value you can use to
>   further categorise Log Entries
>   (defaults to 0 for a LogEntry and to 1
>   for a LogEntry implicitly created by
>   Logger.Write);

Answer (score 0):

What we do is gather the different "stories" that you want to report on and then assign a sequence of event IDs to each of those stories. So in short, come up with a system that works for you and document it for future reference.